# How to avoid temporary table in sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, optimization, temp-tables

I am running a query (taking 3 minutes to execute)-

```
SELECT c.eveDate,c.hour,SUM(c.dataVolumeDownLink)+SUM(c.dataVolumeUpLink) 
FROM cdr c 
WHERE c.evedate>='2013-10-19'
GROUP BY c.hour;
```

with explain plan -

```
id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys                 key  key_len  ref  rows      Extra                                         
1   SIMPLE       c      ALL   evedate_index,eve_hour_index                     31200000  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

I am using table(Myisam)-

> Primary key(id,evedate),
>
> with weekly 8 partitions with key evedate,
>
> index key- on evedate,
>
> composite index on evedate,hour.

I have changed the mysql tuning parameters from my.ini as (4GB RAM)-

> tmp_table_size=200M
>
> key_buffer_size=400M
>
> read_rnd_buffer_size=2M

But still its using temporary table and file sort. Please let me know what should I do to exclude this.

*After adding new composite index(evedate,msisdn)*

I have found some changes in few queries they were not using any temporary case, even in above query if I omit group by clause, its not using temporary table.

Comment: FROM: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/03/05/what-does-using-filesort-mean-in-mysql/

Anytime a sort can’t be performed from an index, it’s a filesort. It has nothing to do with files. Filesort should be called “sort.” It is quicksort at heart.

Comment: but what about temporary file?  i heard that temporary file causes slow query, my above query taking 4 minutes to execute.

Comment: create a sqlfiddle link with sample data.

Comment: @Damodaran i dont know how sqlfiddle works but check this out [sqlfiddle]:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34e2b4/1

Comment: Obviously the GROUP BY clause in your query is making use of Using temporary and Using filesort. I do't know how to remove the group by in mysql. In sql you can achieve this by using over partition by

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do anything. MySql is not able to optimize this query and avoid temporaty table.

According to this link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-optimization.html

there are two methods MySql is using to optimize GROUP BY.

---

The first method - **Loose Index Scan** - cannot be used for your query because this condition is not meet:

> The only aggregate functions used in the select list (if any) are MIN() and MAX() ....

Your query contains SUM, therefore MySql cannot use the above optimalization method.

---

The second method - **Tight Index Scan** - cannot be used for your query, because this condition is not meet:

> For this method to work, it is sufficient that there is a constant equality condition for all columns in a query referring to parts of the key coming before or in between parts of the GROUP BY key.

Your query is using only a range operator : `WHERE c.evedate>='2013-10-19'`, there is no any equality condition in the WHERE clause, therefore this method cannot be used to optimize the query.

Comment: you are right about the above points. But I have read here(stackoverflow) that mysql can handle upto 400 Million records table, and many DBA dealing with such situation daily. So is there any way to achieve some optimization by changing query or changing my.ini parameter or any way?